# SQLite ID column and onItemLongClick

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I have been searching and searching with no luck, this is my code

```js
// Product List
    public void setProductList() {

        productDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();


        Cursor prodView = productDB.getAllData();
        prodView.moveToFirst();
        ArrayAdapter<String> listAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.medicinelistmenu, R.id.productlistsTextView1);

        while (prodView.moveToNext()) {
            listAdaptor.add(prodView.getString(1));
            
        }

        listView.setAdapter(listAdaptor);


        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id) {

                productDB.deleteProduct(id);
                Toast.makeText(medicineList.this, "Item Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());

                return true;
            }

        });
    }
```

With the onItemLongClick function, other posts are telling me the **long** value in the AdapterView will be the SQLLite ID column, however it is the same value as the position in the array.

This is the delete function in my DatabaseHelper class

```
    public void deleteProduct(long ID)
{
    SQLiteDatabase productsdb = this.getWritableDatabase();
    productsdb.execSQL("DELETE FROM  "+ PRODTABLE_NAME +" WHERE ID = "+ ID);

}
```

Can anyone shed any light on how to get the Database ID value please.

Comment: do not use `ArrayAdapter`, use `CursorAdapter` instead, most likely `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: Ok thank you, I will give it a go.

Comment: if you use `SimpleCursorAdapter` the last paramete of `onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id)` is a database ID

Answer (score 1):

**Long is the row id of the item that was clicked, not the id of the product in the DB.** 
Create a method in DBHelper class which return `ID`, having parameter `String productName`

Edit `onItemLongClick()`

```
 @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos, long id) {
            TextView prdName = arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView_prdname);

            // now call the method which take productName as parameter and return productId
            int prdID = productDB.getProductID(prdName.getText().toString());

            // Now Pass that ID to deleteProduct
            productDB.deleteProduct(prdID);
            Toast.makeText(medicineList.this, "Item Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());

            return true;
        }
```

Also if the names are unique instead of `DELETE FROM table WHERE ID = id` you can use 
`DELETE FROM table WHERE NAME = name` Here name can be get from `prdName.getText()` 
 in this way you just need to execute one query.

Comment: `"Long is the row id of the item that was clicked, not the id of the product in the DB."` no, long is the value returned by `Adapter#getItemId(int position)`, `CursorAdapter` implements that method by returning `_id` column

Comment: so what is the difference between `position` and `id` in `onItemLongClick` / `onItemClick` methods? just use `SimpleCursorAdapter` and you will see that `id` is really database ID, not `"row/list_item position"`

Comment: Its alright, but as you see in the question, it's arrayadapter not cursoradapter, this is why I posted this alternative.

Comment: so thats why (and couple of other reasons) `ArrayAdapter` should never be used when dealing with `Cursor` based data, instead `CursorAdapter` needs to be used

Comment: ** i know that.